# Trying to add lables 4 different forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have four forms and they each have an int that’s counting the number of items that are picked in that form. (ie form2 3/10 items, Form2 4/10 items)
There is a max number that is the same among all forms this means that the max amount of items that can be entered is ten.

All I am trying to do is add the top number of each form ( number_p) and have a total count in my form1.

Ie. Form2 3/10, Form3  2/10, Form4 5/10 than Form1 = 10/10.
I have tried to add them as a sum but I cant seem to be able to make the sum appear on the label.

Any suggestions or tips? Thanks

public void Update number_limit ()

```
    {

        if (number_p >= Form1.number_p _Limit)

        {

            number_pLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
    }

        else

        {

            number_pLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;

        }

        number_p 
        number_p _totalLabel.Text = number_p.ToString() + " / " + Form1.number_limit.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: You question is not very clear, for starters the statement…  `if (number_p >= Form1.number_p _Limit)` looks malformed. What is `_Limit` and how is it supposed to be used in the `if` statement? How does each form get its number?

Comment: @JohnG Form1.number_p_limit is variable that's set in Form 1, each form gets a new number on top when a new item is entered. the idea of the if statement is to make sure that the number of items does not pass the limit. thank you

Comment: It appears there is a “ “ space between `Form1.number_p` AND `_Limit`. In addition, you are going to have to show how you are setting this number for each form. If each form has a number and you want to GET this number in form 1… these numbers will have to be accessible to form1. This means these numbers will need to be globally accessible to other active forms. There is not enough information to say WHY you are not able to get these totals. Again, how is each form given this number? In Addition, how is the number defined in each form? Is each number globally accessible?

Comment: @JohnG DialogResult result = additemForm.ShowDialog();

                    if (result == DialogResult.OK) //if an item is successfully added to the database in the "addForm"
                    {
                        
                        number_p++;
                        Updatenumber_p();       this is how my items get added to each individual form all my form are public. is there a way to share DialogResult with Form1? so for example everytime DialogeResult is OK Form1 sees that and adds a number?

Comment: You should edit your question to show how all of this is put together and not a simple malformed `if` statement. From the current post, speculation is about all you will get. Edit your question to be more specific and show VALID code that is not working as expected.

Comment: You may want to take a [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) that shows how SO works. In addition, you may want to peruse, [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), also if you need [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help). Finally… You are going to have to reduce you question to something more specific take a look at. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You don't say whether the four forms are shown modal (one at a time) or modeless (more than one can be used at the same time). I assume modal so what you can do is to create a method (or property) in each form that the main form can call and then after each form is shown call the method for each form and add them up. There are many other ways but that is the simplest to explain and understand.